# How to bind user-supplied method when in the class's constructor?

Tags: python, class, methods, dynamic

I'm designing a class and I would like to make it possible for the user to specify one of the class's methods when initializing an instance of it.

A simple example would be something along the lines of:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, supplied_method):
        self.a = 2
        # what more goes here?


def my_fun(self):
    print(self.a)


my_object = MyClass(my_fun)
my_object.my_fun()
```

Expected output

```
 2
```

---

I tried `self.my_fun = my_fun` in the constructor, but then the `self` argument is not being fed with the instance automatically. I'm also aware that it's possible to bind the method `my_fun` *outside* of the class definition, by using `MethodType`, but I want to bind it in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to *bind* the supplied function to that specific instance. You can do so by calling the [`__get__` descriptor method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) on the function:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, supplied_method):
        self.a = 2
        bound = supplied_method.__get__(self, type(self))
        setattr(self, supplied_method.__name__, bound)
```

I've assumed you wanted the attribute on the instance to use the same name as the function that was passed in; note that this will result in a hard-to-use `<lambda>` attribute when `supplied_method` is a lambda!

Demo:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self, supplied_method):
...         self.a = 2
...         bound = supplied_method.__get__(self, type(self))
...         setattr(self, supplied_method.__name__, bound)
...
>>> def my_fun(self):
...     print(self.a)
...
>>> my_object = MyClass(my_fun)
>>> my_object.my_fun()
2
```

For 'normal' methods, where the function is an attribute of the *class*, attribute access on the instance is delegated to the class object, which handles the descriptor binding for you. See the [*descriptor HOWTO*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: Thank you for your time! This solves the problem. One question that I had (unfortunately after writing this question): how about just writing `MyClass.supplied_method = supplied_method` in `MyClass`'s constructor to bind the supplied method?

Comment: @JLagana: then **all** instances of the class will share that method.

Comment: @JLagana: that's not the same thing as each individual instance having a custom bound method. `instance1 = MyClass(foo)` would first set the class attribute, then `instance2 = MyClass(bar)` would set the same class attribute, and both `instance1.supplied_method()` and `instance2.supplied_method()` would be calling `bar(...)`.